# timer stop activating during while statement

Tags: c#, timer, plc

I have a timer and it pull data from a PLC. I have a part where I write data to a PLC and then I write for a reply from the PLC.
there a flag and I am waiting for it to change to true.
my timer is reading the flag...
but when  I get to my while statement, the timer stops firing up.
why ?
here is my code :

```
  void movePixalLinkCam(int pos)
    {
        bool flag;

        if (state == 2)
        {
            flag = true;
            tcClient.WriteAny(Pos0number, Convert.ToDouble(pos));
            tcClient.WriteAny(Axis0MoveStartnumber, flag);

            while(!Axis0MoveFlag)
            {

            }
            flag = false;
            tcClient.WriteAny(Axis0MoveStartnumber, flag);
        }

        }
```

the timer seem to stop during the while statement .
why?
should I put this function on a different thread or something ?

Update

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
          dataStream.Position = 0;
            tcClient.Read(Axis0MoveFlagnumber, dataStream);
            Axis0MoveFlag = binRead.ReadBoolean();
            dataStream.Position = 0;}
          catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Does Axis0MoveFlag get set to true in a separate thread?  Your while-loop is locking.

Comment: Please show your timer and how you create it (there are multiple types of `Timer`). Also show how you create the `Axis0MoveFlag` (LarsTech is hinting it should be `volatile`, but we can't verify).

Comment: If the Axis0MoveFlag is changed on a different thread have you marked it as [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) to ensure the compiler knows it may change.

Comment: I am using  timer1 from System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: That timer runs on the UI thread, which is being blocked by your loop.  You have to remove that loop.  Just use that timer to run that code after the loop when the flag is true.